# Trying to find a positive root for a polynomial without knowing some coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**:  Let $p$ and $q$ be positive integers. How many distinct quadratic polynomials in   the form $x^2 - px - q = 0$ having a positive root less than $3$?

**My (partial) solution**:

Using the quadratic formula, $\frac{p \pm \sqrt{p^2 + 4q}}{2} < 3$.

Hence, $p \pm \sqrt{p^2 + 4q} < 6$.

So, $p - 6 < \pm \sqrt{p^2 + 4q}$ (you can do this because there is both the negative and positive case).

Squaring both sides, we get $p^2 - 12p + 36 < \pm(p^2 + 4q)$.

For now, we'll look at the positive case of $\pm(p^2 + 4q)$.

Canceling out the $p^2$ from both sides, we get $-12p + 36 < 4q$.

We then get $-3p + 9 < q$.

So, $3p > 9 - q$.

However, I don't know what to do from here. I also don't know if the negative case of $\pm(p^2 + 4q)$ gives any solutions or if it is just a hard case.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your calculation is hard to follow.  Where did you use the fact that the root is required to be positive?

Comment: Yeah, I never said that it was required to be positive. I just said I was looking at the positive case first. Also, I don't know if the negative case works.

Comment: What?  "...having a positive root less than 3?"  is in your question.

Comment: @Yorch   The OP said, in a comment, "I never said that it was required to be positive."  I am simply pointing out that they did.

Comment: "I also don't know if the negative case of $$\pm(p^2 + 4q)$$ gives any solutions or if it is just a hard case." I was starting to suspect that the case wouldn't work.

Comment: @Yorch  Oh, no worries.  I expect the OP was just confused.

Comment: @lulu yes lol probably :)

Comment: It is the *root of the quadratic* that you are requiring to be positive.  The radical then obviously has to be positive (as the root associated with the negative radical will be negative).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127009/discussion-between-i-am-a-person-and-lulu).

Comment: No need to chat.  I think the solution by @Yorch is clear and complete.

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to ask Yorch about their solution because it has a different answer than the one in my packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted the roots are $\frac{p\pm \sqrt{p^2+4q}}{2}$.

Note that the square root to the right is larger in absolute value than $p$, so in order for the root to be positive we must take the root with positive sign.

Hence our problem is equivalent to $p+\sqrt{p^2+4q} < 6$.

I think there are many ways to proceed, but the laziest way (at least at first glance) is to just note that $p$ must be among $\{1,2\}$ (because the part with the root is larger).

So now we just have to check $1+\sqrt{1+4q} < 6$ and $2+\sqrt{4+4q} < 6$ which is equivalent to $1+4q<25$ and $4+4q < 16$ respectively. So there are $5+2$ solutions.

Comment: The answer that I got in my solutions packet is different then what you got in your solution. The answer in my packet is 7. I understand your solution but I'm wondering if there is a little mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Iamaperson the second summand was $2$ sorry about that.

Comment: alright that's ok

Answer (score 1):

With $f(x)=x^2-px-q$, we have $f(0)=-q<0$ and hence this upward parabola has one negative and one positive root. The latter is $<3$ iff $f(3)>0$, i.e., iff
$$ 9-3p-q>0$$
or,
$$3p+q<9. $$
The corresponding $(p,q)$ are readily enumerated.

Comment: Good solution too!